# Add merge field to MS Word Document using Open Office SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I am trying to create a new MS Word document and insert a new merge field using the Microsoft Open Office SDK (v2.0) but the code below does not work (the merge field doesn't appear when I save the resulting stream to a file and open it).  I have searched the internet but have been unable to resolve the issue.

```
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        using (
            WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream,
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

            mainPart.Document = new Document();
            Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

            FieldCode fieldCode = new FieldCode(" MERGEFIELD MyMergeField ");
            body.AppendChild(fieldCode);
            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }

        return stream;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The best thing to do in a case like this is to create a minimal document then view it in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. That generates the Open XML SDK code to create that document. So you can see what's missing or how it needs to be done differently and incorporate that in your code.

Comment: thanks Cindy - if you want to add this as an answer rather than a comment I will mark it as correct

Comment: Thanks, but it's something I suggest so often, and it isn't really a true Answer, that I wouldn't feel right doing so :-) I'm very happy if the suggestion helps you!